# Python: if answer.upper or answer.lower disregards input and always does 1st if

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to have a loop which does something according to Y/N input.
If I use `.upper` / `.lower`, the loop does not work and always goes into the first if, no matter the input. Why is that?

Here's and example of how it doesn't work:

```py
answer = input("Do you want to begin? (Y/N): ")
if answer or answer.lower() in ("y", "yes"):        
    print("Start")
else:
    print("Bye")
```

If I write it like this, it works fine.

```py
if answer in ("y","Y","yes","Yes","YES"):
```

This I found online as solution, but doesn't work for me:

```
if answer.upper() or answer.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
```

Am I just missing something or did anyone else have this issue?
Thanks for the help

Comment: ``a or b in c`` is true when *either* ``a`` is true or ``b in c`` is true.

Comment: you are caught with short circuit evaluation

Comment: Note that if ``answer in ("y", "yes")`` then ``answer.lower() in ("y", "yes")`` as well. It's enough to just test the latter.

Comment: @Epsi95: No, short-circuiting doesn't matter here. The results would be the same without short circuiting.

Comment: @Epsi95 What he's caught in is operator precedence, and also that `or` doesn't distribute.